# Reading stdout data for an open subprocess in Python

Tags: python

I can open a subprocess in Python and *send* it some data, e.g.

```
process = subprocess.Popen( ["bash"], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stdin = subprocess.PIPE )
process.stdin.write( b"echo hello\n" )
```

However, I'm having a problem *receiving* data.
Usually I'd use the following:

```
for line in process.stdout:
    ...do something...
```

But *because the process is still open* it is still generating the data, and so `line` is empty until `stdout` actually gets the data, and the loop exits before it ever starts. Similarly I can't use `process.communicate` because while this does get the data, it does so only because it waits for the process to exit.

I can of course poll, for instance *this does work*:

```
while True:
    line = process.stdout.readline()
    
    if line:
        ...do something...
```

However, polling is very resource consuming!
Is there a better (crossplatform) alternative?

Comment: I would expect `readline` to block until there is a line of data available, or until the stream is closed.  Are you sure there aren't blank lines coming back from the other process?

Comment: As Steve says -- `for line in process.stdout:` will just wait until there _is_ a line available; the only time it exits is if `stdout` has already been closed. It _does not_ exit if the process is still running and no output is yet written, unless that process _actually closed its stdout_.

Comment: Also, `line = process.stdout.readline()` should not be a poll operation -- it, too, should block until there's something actually ready to be read -- unless something is actually setting the non-blocking flag on the file descriptor; but if you're doing something like that, it really needs to be included in the code in the question.